# When to use ExceptionFilter vs BaseExceptionFilter in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

What is the diff b/w both types of filters. And when to use what? Please explain with any example

```
@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {

}

@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter extends BaseExceptionFilter {

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ExceptionFilter` is an interface that defines that the current class should implement the `catch` method with the signature `(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentHost)`.

`BaseExceptionFilter` is a class already made in NestJS with a working `catch` method. By using `extend` you can add your own logic to `catch` and then in the end of the implementation call `super.catch(exception, host)` and let Nest take care of the rest from there.

The main difference of the two is how much of the logic do you want to write vs how much do you want to add in. If you are happy with how Nest already handles errors, and just want to add in the ability to log your errors, say to a database, then `extends BaseExceptionFilter` is a good fit. However, if you don't care or how Nest's exception filter works by default, then `implements ExceptionFilter` and writing your own custom logic is the way to go.

Comment: Would you please provide one example or usecase for implementing ExceptionFilter?

Comment: Like I said, when you don't like how Nest's `BaseExceptionFilter` works and you want your own logic in there. Not sure how to really give an example of it because it varies so much on a case to case basis. I guess the biggest thing would be you always want to send HTTP 200, but you have specialized error codes in your response payload.